# How to redraw the UIBezierpath based textview text contentsize in iphone

Tags: iphone, resize, ios6, uitextview, uibezierpath

I draw the message bubble using UIBezierpath in uiview. I render the textview inside the bezier path. My problem is when I enter the text in textview I want to message bubble size dynamically increase but I cannot do that. how can resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can resize the UIBezierpath relative to your UITextview frame size like this:

```
CGRect box = CGPathGetBoundingBox(bezierpath.CGPath)
CGFloat scaleX = textView.frame.size.width / box.frame.size.width;
CGFloat scaleY = textView.frame.size.height / box.frame.size.height;
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scaleX, scaleY);
CGPathRef intermediatePath = CGPathCreateCopyByTransformingPath(bezierpath.CGPath, &transform);
bezierPath.CGPath = intermediatePath;
CFRelease(intermediatePath);
```

Hope that help!

Comment: where should i use this inside -(void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView or else

Comment: yes! is your textview dynamically resized also, or you have textview of fixed height?

Comment: If you are drawing UIBezierpath inside view's drawrect method? than you can do the scaling inside drawrect method also and just need to call that view's setNeedsDisplay in textViewDidChange