# How to autoresize sublayers

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, drawing, uibezierpath

I have an imageview and on button click I draw some bezier paths and some text layer too. On undo, I've removed last drawn path and text layer.

Now I want to resize my image View to set up in uper half portion of view and duplicated in lower half view, and want to resize all layers at the same time and also want to continue drawing after that.

Comment: Duplicate your view i.e other instance of its class with same attributes.apply cgaffinetranslation 1/2 on xscale. on both copies place one below other see if it works

Comment: I think you are not updating your bezier path while resizing the image view. You can find a way for updating bezier path here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13524022/how-to-redraw-the-uibezierpath-based-textview-text-contentsize-in-iphone

Answer (score 21):

Its too late to answer...

But may be this can help others. There is no autoresize masks for CALayers 
You can manage that with some tricks..

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
  // resize your layers based on the view's new frame
  layer.frame = self.bounds;
}
```

This will work if you have created a subclass of UIView. If not that, you can just set the bounds to the frame of CALayer anywhere if you have reference to your layer.

Comment: Thanks +1! it's work for me with: self.sublayer.frame = self.layer.bounds;

Comment: But it doesn't work with autolayouted view with CALayers while rotate :))

Answer (score 4):

At least there are 3 options:

1. use delegate of `CALayer`
2. override `layoutSublayers`, and call it by `setNeedsLayout()`
3. use extension and call view's `fitLayers`

Example below, **option 3**:

### Swift 5, 4

#### Code

```
extension UIView {
  func fitLayers() {
    layer.fit(rect: bounds)
  }
}

extension CALayer {
  func fit(rect: CGRect) {
    frame = rect

    sublayers?.forEach { $0.fit(rect: rect) }
  }
}
```

#### Example

```
// inside UIViewController 
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {    
  super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

  view.fitLayers()
}

// or
// inside UIView
override func layoutSubviews() {    
  super.layoutSubviews()

  fitLayers()
}
```

Comment: Thank you! If you're going to use it in the UIView, you need to subclass UIView: 

import UIKit

class CustomView : UIView {

    /*
    // Only override draw() if you perform custom drawing.
    // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        // Drawing code
    }
    */
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
      super.layoutSubviews()

      fitLayers()
    }

}